# python 2.7 OSX 10.10 package problems

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm using :
mac osx 10.10.1

Yesterday I started to get errors using same packages that I normally use.
After few hrs I decided to remove python from my mac

I installed  python again following this instructions:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/#install-osx
(i a nut shell I installed python 2.7 using HomeBrew)

```
from the shell:
$python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 19 2014, 16:02:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

from the shell:
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

from the shell:
$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I installed pip
I installed few pkgs using $ pip install command

when I try to just import openpyxl
I'm getting this:

```
import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
from .workbook import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 11, in <module>
import threading
File   
"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/
Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", 
line 14, in <module>
from time import time as _time, sleep as _sleep
ImportError: cannot import name time
```

please can you help me out?
thanks
d

additional info:

meanwhile I tried to do same thing  else to fix the problem
(I didn't fix it)

Basically I installed virtualenv
I created a basic virtual env 
I have a new folder with python and all the pkgs

```
(venv_002)danielepemys-MacBook-Pro:my_python_virtualenv danielepemy$ which python
/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/bin/python
```

everything looks fine,  python works, pip works the pkgs are listed in the virtual env

```
(venv_002)danielepemys-MacBook-Pro:my_python_virtualenv danielepemy$ pip list

pip (1.5.6)

setuptools (3.6)

wsgiref (0.1.2)

XlsxWriter (0.6.4)


when I run a simple test script with XlsxWriter I get:

python ..//internet_speed_test_002.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "..//internet_speed_test_002.py", line 28, in <module>

    excel_file.close()

  File "/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 286, in close

    self._store_workbook()

  File "/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 509, in _store_workbook

    xml_files = packager._create_package()

  File "/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 142, in _create_package

    self._write_core_file()

  File "/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 325, in _write_core_file

    core._assemble_xml_file()

  File "/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/core.py", line 57, in _assemble_xml_file

    self._write_dcterms_created()

  File "/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/core.py", line 122, in _write_dcterms_created

    date = self._localtime_to_iso8601_date(date)

  File "/Users/danielepemy/my_python_virtualenv/venv_002/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/core.py", line 76, in _localtime_to_iso8601_date

    return date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")


AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'struct_time'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any files called `time.py` or `time.pyc` in your current directory? If so, rename or delete them (`.pyc` files can simply be deleted).

Comment: Hi I did as you asked but nothing changed.